# Safari 17 hangs on opening a new link if no windows open

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

#### The Problem

On opening a new link when there are no Safari windows, but Safari is already active, Safari will hang (complete with beach ball) for ~10–30 seconds.

#### Reproduction Steps

1. Have Safari **open** but with no windows
2. Click a link in any app, open a bookmark with Alfred, or enter a URL with Alfred or Spotlight.
3. If Safari opens **both** the link and a blank tab, Safari beach balls for between 10–30 seconds.

#### Specs

- Safari v17.1 (19616.2.9.11.7)
- macOS v14.1.1 (23B81)
- MacBook Pro 14" (2021, M1 Pro, 32GB RAM)

#### Things I Have Tried

- Disabling all extensions.
- Occurs with or without a network connection.
- Doesn't reproduce on a test user account.
- Clearing website data: **Settings > Privacy > Manage Website Data > Remove All**.
- Setting Safari as the default browser (previously BetterTouchTool was) from **Settings > General > Set Safari as Default Browser**.
- Quitting BetterTouchTool just to be safe.
- Restarting my Mac.

#### Things I have noticed

- Whenever the hang happens, I have noticed that Safari will open a second, blank tab. So, although I have only clicked one link, two tabs open.
- In Activity Monitor, the Safari process says it is using ~100% CPU when the beach ball happens. All the other Safari processes (extensions, networking SafariLaunchAgent, etc) seem normal.
- Frustratingly, it doesn't happen every time! It will be fine for 3-4 fresh links and then the problem will reoccur.
  It doesn't matter what URL I go to.
  It doesn't happen at the same point. Sometimes happens before the page loads, and sometimes after the page loads. But always within about 60 seconds of the new window opening.
- Clicking on Safari in the dock to open a new window, and entering the URL into the address bar, doesn't cause the fault.

I am a bit stumped about what to try next. Every time I think I've narrowed the culprit down, I manage to reproduce the problem. Suggestions for things to try or ways to narrow down the fault gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this, as was suggested [by @cornchip on the Mac Power Users Forum](https://talk.macpowerusers.com/t/need-help-troubleshooting-a-safari-17-beachball/35459/2?u=aarblaster), I tried using Safari Technology Preview.
Having installed it and set it as default the problem is resolved for now. A feedback has been lodged.
Feedback FB13384650